# How can i replace a { with {}

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am trying to develop a braces auto completion feature in a text box. I tried the javascript replace function on the textbox. But i am getting a weird output from the function. Here's the code i am work on.

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type ="text" id="textbox">
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**:

```
var element = document.getElementById('textbox');
element.oninput = function(){
 var code = (function(){
      var val = element.value;
      element.value = val.replace(/\{/ , "{}");  
 })();
};
```

When i type a single `{` brace i am getting `{}` , when i type more than 1 i am getting `{}}}{{` and it goes on ..  sometimes my browser freezes when i try to clear the braces.

Here's the js bin link [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/bofivivafu/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: haha omg your function seems to work on all of my chrome tabs. I have to restart chrome to get rid of it. I have been trolled.

Comment: It doesn't affect my other tabs, but it did affect the JSBin JavaScript pane.  Self modifying code!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are always replacing `{` with `{}`, even if the bracket has already been matched. You should instead ensure it was not with [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `/\{(?!\})/`

---

To fix the backspace issue, you should instead be using an event which can tell you which key was pressed like `onkeyup` and add a guard clause. Expanding on @Andi's idea, I also added exclusion for the arrow keys so you won't be forced to the end of the textbox when you want to navigate through the text:

```
var element = document.getElementById('textbox');
element.onkeyup = function(){
    if([8, 37, 39].indexOf(event.which) != -1)
        return false;
    var code = (function(){
         var val = element.value;
         element.value = val.replace(/\{(?!\})/g, "{}");  
    })();
};
```

Comment: stil it's not working :( http://jsbin.com/bofivivafu/edit?html,js,console,output
and the backspace is not working though after the replace.. @ndn

Comment: @Xcoder, it is working for me. The backspace thing should be ignored when you do the change event though, because it will reapply the replace.

Comment: could you please show me an example with change event.. That would be appreciable

Comment: @Xcoder, Andi beat me to it. You should instead use an event that tells you which key was pressed and check against the backspace code.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/bofivivafu/edit?html,js,console,output .. There's a lag in the textbox while inserting the {.. Any idea..

Comment: @Xcoder, I don't experience any lag with the link you gave. What browser are you using?

Comment: try deleting and adding the brace , I am also experiencing a lag

Comment: @Xcoder, fixed. I added a `g` flag to the regex so it will do all replaces simultaneously.

Comment: Insert a brace in the textbox and insert a brace in the js bin code editor.. You can see the difference ..There's still a lag brother :(

Comment: @Xcoder, Are you still experiencing lag with [this version](http://jsbin.com/niyojuweqa/1/edit?html,js,console,output)?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex matches '{', you should exclude all '{}':

Snippet: [regex : `/(?!{})\{/` ]

```js
var element = document.getElementById('textbox');
element.oninput = function() {
  var code = (function() {
    var val = element.value;
    element.value = val.replace(/(?!{})\{/, "{}");
  })();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="textbox">
</body>

</html>
```

**Update (With Backspace working):**

Need to use keyboard event so that we can get keycode of the key pressed. Use `onkeyup`

```js
var element = document.getElementById('textbox');
element.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.which != 8) {
    var val = element.value;
    element.value = val.replace(/(?!{})\{/, "{}");
  }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="textbox">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The issue is still there , click the backspace on your live snippet.

Comment: @Xcoder : I have updated the answer, have a look please.

Answer (score 1):

Regexs may become heavy for an autocompletion tool, especially with  negative lookaheads.

Actually, you do not have to look for braces at each input, just test the character typed with `onkeypress` event.

And you should also put the caret into the braces, otherwise you have still one keystroke because you have to move back :)

```js
var element = document.getElementById('textbox');

element.onkeypress = function(evt){
    
    switch(String.fromCharCode(evt.which)){
        case "{": 
            var currentCaretPosition= this.selectionStart;
            
            var text= this.value;
            this.value= text.slice(0, currentCaretPosition)+
                        "{\n\t\n}"+
                        text.slice(currentCaretPosition,text.length );
              
      this.setSelectionRange(  currentCaretPosition+3, currentCaretPosition+3 );
            evt.preventDefault();
    }
};
```

```css
#textbox{
    border:inset 1px #aaa;
    width:80vw;
    height:80vw;
    margin:2vw;
    padding:0.5vw
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textbox">
function test()
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole sting is evaluated each time the function is called.

`{` -> `{}`
if you now add another `}` you get `{}}{}`

```
use val.replace(/\{$/ , "{}");
```

The `$` only evaluates the last character. Here you can try to build regex queries:
https://regex101.com/r/iU4xT9/1

PS: Maybe it gets weirds when you delete the last `}` you could only call the function, when you add characters and ignore the delete key.

```
var element = document.getElementById('textbox');
element.onkeyup = function(event){
 if(event.which == 8)
   return false
 var code = (function(){
      var val = element.value;
      element.value = val.replace(/\{$/ , "{}");  
 })();
};
```

Comment: http://jsbin.com/bofivivafu/edit?html,js,console,output still the browser freezes when i click the backspace..

Comment: @Xcoder, it doesn't freeze, it just deletes the last character and does a replace (adds it again) faster than you can see it. Unless you mean that your browser actually freezes (becomes not responding), in which case - what browser are you using?

Comment: Actually the browser does not freeze but imediatelly when you delete the last `}` it adds a `}` again. I

Comment: how to fix that issue @AndiGiga

Comment: I posted a solution above. Try that one.

Comment: @AndiGiga  http://jsbin.com/bofivivafu/edit?html,js,console,output still the problem is there.. see the bin

Comment: In the bin are two functions oninput and onkeyup. Delete this part `};

element.oninput = function(){` So that everything is within the onkeyup function.

Comment: I tried and it works . But there's a lag .. http://jsbin.com/bofivivafu/edit?html,js,console,output .. see the bin

Comment: It doe not lag on my browser. Can't reproduce it, sorry.

Comment: try adding and deleting a brace.

Comment: I did. Does not lag on my computer. Maybe try to move the function outside the keyup and just call it.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/wumanajuho/edit?html,js,console,output .. i tried it.. but still . :( you can see the difference , insert a brace in the textbox , do the same in the js bin code editor.  There's difference..